# How do I run a diff of short file names?

Tags: bash, directory, filenames, diff

I'm using bash shell.  I want to see a diff of file names in two directories, but only of direct children of those directories.  So for instance, if I have these directories with child files/dirs named ...

```
dir1
-> abc
-> def
-> ghi

dir2
-> abc
-> fff
-> ghi
```

I would like to be able to run some command that would tell me that dir2 has a file/dir named "fff" that dir1 doesn't have, whereas "dir1" has a child file/dir named "def" that dir2 doesn't have.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
for name in dir1/* dir2/*; do
    bname=${name##*/}

    if [ ! -e "dir1/$bname" ]; then
        printf '"%s" not in dir1\n' "$bname"
    elif [ ! -e "dir2/$bname" ]; then
        printf '"%s" not in dir2\n' "$bname"
    fi
done
```

This will iterate over all names in `dir1` and `dir2`. `$bname` will be the basename of the name (`$name` without path).

If the (base)name can not be found in `dir1`, then this is reported. Otherwise, if it's not found in `dir2` it's reported.

This copes with filenames containing embedded newlines and should run with `/bin/sh` or any compatible `sh` shell.

This could potentially be expanded to more than two directories.  With `bash`:

```
dirs=( dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 )

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    for name in "$dir"/*; do

        bname=${name##*/}

        for tdir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
            if [ ! -e "$tdir/$bname" ]; then
                printf '"%s" not found in %s\n' "$bname" "$tdir"
            fi
        done

    done
done
```

---

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   `-- filename 1
|-- dir2
|   |-- filename 1
|   |-- filename 3
|   `-- hello
world
`-- script.sh

$ sh script.sh
"filename 3" not in dir1
"hello
world" not in dir1
```

Comment: This is quite nice!

Answer (score 0):

For this I quite like `comm -3`, on plain `ls`’s output:

```
$ comm -3 <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
def
        fff
```

Entries in the first column are only in the first directory, entries in the second column are only in the second directory; the `-3` option removes the third column which displays entries common to both. You can also specify `-1` to only see files present in `dir2` but not in `dir1`, and `-2` to only see files present in `dir1` but not in `dir2`.

For this to work you need to ensure you don’t have any options set for `ls`, either *via* its `OPTIONS` configuration or an alias. You can avoid such issues using a variant such as

```
$ comm -z -3 <(cd dir1; printf "%s\0" *) <(cd dir2; printf "%s\0" *) | tr '\0' '\n'
def
        fff
```

The latter avoids issues with special characters in filenames. You can combine it with `-1` or `-2` and drop the `tr` to feed it into `xargs -0` for further processing of either set of files too.

Comment: `ls` is problematic, f.i. on my Linux machines I have `OPTIONS="-b -T 0 --quoting-style=shell"`.  With this a file named `a b` is listed as `'a b'`.

Comment: Hey this doens't work.  It is listing files taht are in both directories and that isn't what I want.

Comment: @Dave see my update, you can change `comm`’s options to see exactly what you want.

Comment: @SatōKatsura that can be avoided, see my update.